# Can I use OCSP for signer's certificate and CRL for CA's certifiter to enable LTV

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

I'm trying to enable LTV when sign a PDF usign iText7. To be able to enable LTV, I need to add OCSP or CRL into the signature. The problem is I only have OCSP for my signer's certificate, not my CA's certificate because our root CA doesn't provide it.

[image]

Because typically CRL respose is quite large (upto a few MB and increase over time)
so I want to avoid using it whenever possible. I wonder if I could use OCSP for signer's certificate and CRL for CA's certifiter to enable LTV?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately you don't show your relevant code here. Assuming you use `com.itextpdf.signatures.LtvVerification.addVerification(String, IOcspClient, ICrlClient, CertificateOption, Level, CertificateInclusion)`, have you considered the `Level` `OCSP_OPTIONAL_CRL`, in comments specified as *Include CRL only if OCSP can't be read*?

Comment: Thank you for you response. I'm using this after using SignExternalContainer

`byte[] sh = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(preSigning.GetHash(), iText.Signatures.PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, _ocspRes, _resCrl);`
And using this code: 
`byte[] encodedSig = sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(item.DocumentHash, iText.Signatures.PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, tSAClient, _ocspRes, _resCrl);`
before calling signDeferred. I have already been able to enable LTV with this code using CRL, I just want to know if I could use CRL for my CA'cert and OCSP for my signer's cert.

Comment: In that case you can combine a single OCSP response and any number of CRLs. IIRC, iText here only expects the BasicOcspResponse and builds the full response around it.

Comment: I tried using only signer's cert OCSP response and CA's cert CRL but it wasn't working. So I guess that I can only enable LTV with either OCSP responses or CRL for both certificates, right?

Comment: Well, "LTV-enabled" is a proprietary Adobe concept, so they may of course introduce weird restrictions any time. But there is no reason to restrict to a single type of revocation information, and the last time i checked mixed types worked, so i would assume there was some other issue in your attempt.

Comment: Could you give me the code for that? Thank you!

Comment: I checked by validating an existing PDF with mixed embedded revocation information. I don't have code for that ready to share.

Comment: It's a shame. Thank you anyway, I'll figure it out myself.

Comment: @mkl I tried so hard but I still can't make it LTV enabled, here is my file, could you please give it a look and tell me what's wrong? [PDF file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19yqttrSaKa-vv7I67M72U23H_O1u7YXR/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*A copy of [my answer](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/ltv-is-not-enabled-eventhough-ocsp-and-crl-added/m-p/13980793#M101395) to the [cross-posted question](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/ltv-is-not-enabled-eventhough-ocsp-and-crl-added/m-p/13980793) on Adobe Support Community:*</sub>

The certificate whose revocation information are missing is the OCSP responder certificate.

When you are in the situation of viewing the revocation information of the signer certificate, please press the "Signer Details..." button. You'll see something similar to this:

[image: Screenshot]

So the revocation information are missing for this certificate.

By the way, this certificate actually is fairly unusual, often OCSP responder certificates include the extension **id-pkix-ocsp-nocheck** which specifies that an OCSP client can trust a responder for the lifetime of the responder's certificate, no additional checks needed.

Another specialty is that the OCSP responder certificate contains an AIA entry with an OCSP entry for retrieving revocation information... But if one asks that responder, the answer is signed again by the OCSP responder certificate in question. That response obviously is not helpful; depending on the OCSP client software, it can even result in a never-ending loop of OCSP requests...